# Deleting matrix elements efficiently

Tags: matlab

I want to efficiently delete a lot of data from the beginning of a matrix of dimension 2*n.  The matrix looks like this:

```
x1 x2
x3 x4
...
...
```

I want to delete all rows that have the the first element of a row that is smaller than some number and stop when a row isn't smaller (the elements are in numerical order)

What I do at the moment is slow:

```
while 1 
   if list{i}(1) <= someNumber
      list{i}(1,:) = []
   else
      break;
   end
end
```

There must be a neat way of doing this quickly in MATLAB?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just compare the entire first column in one go and then delete, i.e.

```
rows2delete = list{i}(:,1) <= someNumber; %# creates logical array with 1 for deletion
list{i}(rows2delete,:) = []; %# delete some rows, all corresponding cols
```

Comment: Awesome Jonas, that's all I needed.  I knew there must be a good way to get MatLab to do it but it's not one of my languages :).  Will accept when min time has passed.  Thank you.. that shaves of a lot of time.

Comment: @vivid-colours: btw, if you need to do this for all cells in the list, you can use `cellfun` for a one-liner: `list = cellfun(@(x)x(x(:,1)>someNumber,:),list,'uniformOutput',false)`. This keeps, for each array in `list`, the rows where the first value is larger than `someNumber`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. really helped me.  I have just posted a similar problem that you might be interested in.  I need to learn how to do these sort of things better in MATLAB.